# Setting Actions for PopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I have created an NSPopUpButton programmatically and I made an array for my choices, how can I create a setAction for each individual array choice? Thanks!

```
NSRect buttonRect = NSMakeRect(1705, 145, 78, 50); 

    //Button Array.  When I pick the choice it closes the diologue box
    NSArray *newArray;
    NSString *color1 = @"Blue Color";
    NSString *color2 = @"Green Color";
    NSString *color3 = @"Clear Color";

    newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: color1, color2, color3, nil];

    NSPopUpButton *button = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonRect pullsDown:YES];
    [self addSubview:button];
    [button addItemsWithTitles:newArray];
    //want my action for each individual string
    [button setAction:@selector(changeFilterColor)];

-(void) changeFilterColor
{
    NSLog(@"colorChanged");

}
```

Comment: it looks like you're missing a [button setTarget:self]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the [`NSMenuDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/) protocol to your interface (.h file):

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSMenuDelegate>
```

Then:

```
[[button menu]setDelegate:self];
```

after you create the `NSPopUpButton`. Also, remove the line with `setAction:`.

Copy this delegate method:

```
-(void)menu:(NSMenu *)menu willHighlightItem:(NSMenuItem *)item
{
    if ([item.title isEqualToString:@"Blue Color"]) { ... } //etc
}
```

Add the necessary if statements to complete the comparisons.

Comment: What do I add into the protocol? the `-(void)menu:` ?

Answer (score 3):

Another option for this is the use the `setAction` method you originally had in your code. But then for the selector you choose to call set it up to receive a sender object. Something like this:

```
-(void)method:(NSMenuItem *)sender
```

Then you can verify that the sender object is valid and get the title from that instead. I'm a little wary of using `NSMenuDelegate` for this.